# How do I assign scales (or physical dimensions) to HDF5 datasets in h5py?

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I am trying to export scientific data via h5py into an HDF5 container format to be read by other software.

I have a 7-dimensional numpy array for which I create a dataset via h5py.File.create_dataset(). This works fine.

However, I cannot find any way to assign any physical scale (say meters, kg, angle, …) to these 7 dimensions in h5py. I could not find any documentation on how to do this.

This is possible according to the [HDF5 reference](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/Tutor/h5dimscale.html).

Is this implemented in h5py? I know that it is possible with HDF5.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8):

Dimension scales in HDF5 are simply another dataset that is associated with your first dataset. They can be used to define spatial coordinates, for example. If you want to indicate that a particular dimension has certain physical units you can label the dimension, which is done using the HDF5 dimension scale API: `H5DSset_label()`.

[Dimension scales](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dims.html) are possible in h5py, using `h5py.dims.create_scale()` and `h5py.dims.attach_scale()`, and `h5py.dims.label` to set the label.

For example, to indicate that the first dimension of `foo.dat:/data` is in kg and the second in metres, you can set its label as follows (with `f` being the HDF5 file):

```
f['data'].dims[0].label = 'kg'
f['data'].dims[1].label = 'm'
```

To add a dataset as a height scale to the second dimension, you first need to create a scale, then attach the dataset:

```
f['data'].dims.create_scale(f['h'], 'height')
f['data'].dims[1].attach_scale(f['h'])
```

You can then access the labels with

```
[dim.label for dim in f['data'].dims]
```

and the dimension scales themselves with

```
f['data'].dims[1][0]
```

or

```
f['data'].dims[1]['height']
```

Comment: @PiHalbe Is this what you wanted to do?

Comment: I did not find the time to test it yet, but it looks very promising.

Comment: are scale well suited to attach a time vector to temporal data ? Let's says I have a (1024,) vector of temperatures and a time vector giving the hours I made the measures. Does it make sense if the time vector is attached as scale to the temperature vector.dims[0] ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want an attribute:

```
http://code.google.com/p/h5py/wiki/HowTo#Reading_and_writing_attributes
```

Comment: HDF5 documentation indicates that there is a special way to do this, see here: http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/Tutor/h5dimscale.html